# Extract number with R

Tags: r

Thanks for your answer. But I have another question I have this vector:

V1 <- ( "Niveau ⇾ 1.1 Support façade","Façade 1 ⇾ 10 Jonction ouvrage balcon", "Lgt B2-001 ⇾ 20 Menuiseries ext. 1", "Local poubelle ⇾ 20 Menuiseries ext. 1" ,"Laverie ⇾ 20 Menuiseries ext. 1","Lgt B2-101 ⇾ 6 Balcons 1","Lgt B2-511 ⇾ 17 Scellement siphon 1")

I need to have the number after the arrow(⇾).How can I do ?

Eg: I have "Niveau ⇾ 1.1 Support façade" I need 1.1

strsplit(datafqp$`Zone Reserve creat`, split = '[ ]')[[900]][4]

Comment: We can use `readr::parse_number(str1)#
[1] 20` or `library(stringr); as.integer(str_extract(str1, "\\d+"))`

Comment: Adding to @akrun or   in Base R `sub(".*?\\b(\\d+)\\b.*", "\\1", String)`

Comment: I have several sentence I need to have only the number after "E>" in the sentence and I have several sentence : " Niveau <U+21FE> 7 Chape", "Parking 1 <U+21FE> 20 Menuiseries ext. 1", "Façade 1 <U+21FE> 10 Jonction ouvrage balcon" .      Par example I need 7, 20 and 10

Answer (score 0):

We can use `str_extract` with regex lookaround to find the numbers that follow `>`

```
library(stringr)
as.numeric(str_extract(v1, "(?<=\\>\\s)\\d+"))
#[1]  7 20 10
```

#### data

```
v1 <- c("Niveau <U+21FE> 7 Chape", "Parking 1 <U+21FE> 20 Menuiseries ext. 1", 
      "Façade 1 <U+21FE> 10 Jonction ouvrage balcon" )
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I have another question I have this vector: 
 V1 <- ( "Niveau ⇾ 1.1 Support façade","Façade 1 ⇾ 10 Jonction ouvrage balcon", "Lgt B2-001 ⇾ 20 Menuiseries ext. 1", "Local poubelle ⇾ 20 Menuiseries ext. 1" ,"Laverie ⇾ 20 Menuiseries ext. 1","Lgt B2-101 ⇾ 6 Balcons 1","Lgt B2-511 ⇾ 17 Scellement siphon 1")                                               
                           
     I need to have the number after the arrow. How can I do

Comment: @AdrienKagame  Please update it in your post.  From the comments, the formatting of the characters is not getting right

Comment: I truy to keep the solution of my problem but I can't get it. Its possible to help me to get a solution ?